# Yii authorized access for the site index page

Tags: yii

I am building administration backend (in yii) for the web app, and it should be disabled for usual users. In other words I have to make private access for http://www.taxitaxi.kz/dispatcher/index.php. I tried to insert some accessRules in sitecontroller, but it works in another way. 
Awaiting your advices, thanks.

Comment: Another way means what way it works ??

Answer (score 0):

Add the rule in accessRules of your controller

```
array('allow',
'actions'=>array('actionName'),
'users'=>array('admin')
)
```

Comment: I did the same, but no result. I put this code in my SiteController. By the way, I put accessRules into siteController manually (by default there is no such function)

Comment: You should update your question and add the code you have in your SiteController.

Answer (score 0):

To make the controller use the rules you define in `accessRules` you also need to configure the `accessControl` filter.

```
public function filters()
{
    return array('accessControl');
}
```